# valid string for formControlName

Tags: angular

I created a reactive form with keys that can be "special". It seems that not all strings are valid for `formControlName` even if the application runs.

**Component Template:**

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <label>Special key</label><input formControlName="(0.1, 0.2]" type="checkbox">
    <label>Regular key</label><input formControlName="regular" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <button (click)="applyFilter()">Apply</button>
</form>
{{form.value | json}}
```

**Component Logic:**

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      '(0.1, 0.2]': false,
      'regular': false
    });
  }

  applyFilter() {
    let x: Map<string, boolean> = new Map()
    Object.keys(this.form.value)
      .filter(key => {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(this.form.get(key)?.value)
        return this.form.get(key)?.value
      })
      .forEach(key => x.set(key, true))
      console.log(x)
  }
}
```

After clicking the button you can see in the log that the value for `(0.1, 0.2]` is `undefined` whereas this has been set to `false`. I guess it's because the key is "special" (special characters? space?)

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqpzgm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I don't know that it's explicitly mentioned anywhere, but I believe the value for `formControlName` has to follow the same rules as the `name` attribute in HTML.

Comment: @Chellappanவ Sounds like an answer :).

Comment: @Chellappanவ Feel free to put your comment as an answer

Comment: I posted it as answer!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's beacause angular allows to traverse formgroup with string
> delimited by dots. Since there is dot in formControl the key '(0.1,
> 0.2]' it's not working.

[For Reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9e30824ef8d9af87c5c4a4b09bbc42f19ad8f7d5/aio/aio-builds-setup/dockerbuild/scripts-js/lib/common/github-api.ts#L31)